# Is there any flag within the compiler to precompile IPV6 only

Tags: ipv6

I have written the code for IPv6 implementation using a flag setting. The flag needs to be set in the header file before the compilation process if I need to enable IPv6 part. Is there any flag provided with the compiler itself so that I just need to use the statement #ifdef COMPILER_FLAG_FOR_IPV6 to enable IPv6 part of code. If not then IPv4 part is compiled. I dont want to manually define a flag here rather use a inbuilt flag for IPV6.

Comment: Which operating system? I can't say what Visual Studio does, but on Unix-style operating systems the compiler doesn't know this kind of information per se - that's what autoconf and friends are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 compatibility is not dependent upon compiler support, rather OS-specific header files. There is no standard way of testing this as such. (As was pointed out you'd probably want CMake/AutoConf/Some other build system to detect this).

You can also achieve what you seem to be looking for more directly, on Linux for example you can probably do:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#ifdef AF_INET6
....
#endif
```

I'm not sure I'd want to bet on how portable/reliable this is though, I'd guess it would work with any implementation of `sys/socket.h` and a quick look through `winsock2.h` seems to have a similar `#define` of `AF_INET6` too.

Comment: @awoodland...Here if I am using a macro defined by me like #define ENABLEIPv6 1 then the code is working fine. But, if I am using AF_INET6 macro which is defined in sys/socket.h. Even after including this header file at every place the code is not running well. Its getting stuck in the "connect" part of socket programming. Am I missing something? Please suggest if there is something wrong or any other measure needs to be taken.

Comment: my guess would be that you've missed a `#include` somewhere which means `AF_INET6` won't be defined and so you'll be mixing arguments in strange ways possibly.

Comment: @awoodland....I have checked for all the places. #include <sys/socket.h> is included there. Now, I dont understand what may be the reason. I dont understand the reason to get stuck in connect function.

Comment: Any debug info? The output from strace might be relevant/helpful in finding out why it's getting stuck.

Comment: From the traces i can just confirm that the connect function is not working